# Delete all tables by cursor(fetch table names) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have metadata table with a `stg_table` column. That's the name of the `STAGE` database table in `dbo` schema. I want to drop tables if exists by cursor when insert_type column is 'select'.

Metadata example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBQJp.jpg

And my code of cursor :

```
declare kursor cursor for 
     select * 
     from METADATA.dbo.META_SOURCESTAGE;

declare @insert_type varchar(15), 
        @stg_table varchar(30), 
        @src varchar(80), 
        @SQL varchar(254);

open kursor

fetch next from kursor into @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if @insert_type = 'select'
        begin
        select @SQL = 'IF OBJECT_ID('+@stg_table+') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE '+@stg_table
    exec(@SQL)

    fetch next from kursor into @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;
    end
    if @insert_type = 'bulk'
        execute ('truncate table ' + @stg_table);

    print @stg_table;

    fetch next from kursor into @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;
end

close kursor;
deallocate kursor;
```

I would like to remove all existing tables from STAGE.dbo.* by cursor created at METADATA table.

I get an error :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The multi-part identifier "STAGE.dbo.STG_KLIENT" could not be bound.
>   STAGE.dbo.STG_MELDUNEK
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The multi-part identifier "STAGE.dbo.STG_MIEJSCOWOSC" could not be bound.
>   STAGE.dbo.STG_PRACOWNIK

@EDIT
Changed the code - added begin/end but gets still the same error.

Comment: If you want to execute **multiple statements** after an `IF`, you **must use** a `BEGIN .... END` block - otherwise **only** the very next statement is inside the `IF` part - anything beyond that will be executed in all cases......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining about not being able to bound in the `OBJECT_ID` call, your code results in something like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(STAGE.dbo.STG_KLIENT) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE STAGE.dbo.STG_KLIENT
```

The `DROP TABLE` part is fine, but you need to quote the table name in your call to `OBJECT_ID` as it expects a `(N)VARCHAR` input, so go with:

```
select @sql = 'IF OBJECT_ID('''+@stg_table+''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE '+@stg_table
--                           ^^            ^^
```

Also, your code is a bit all over the place. It will skip some tables because what you're doing is:

1. Fetch from cursor (1st result, let's assume of select type)
2. Check if @insert_type = 'select', true so let's enter the block

   - drop table if it exists
   - fetch from cursor (2nd result, let's assume again of select type
   - leave if block
3. Check if @insert_type = 'insert', false, don't truncate
4. print table name
5. fetch next from cursor -> 3rd result, you just did nothing with the 2nd result where you should have dropped it.

Here's a slightly improved version:

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if @insert_type = 'select'
    begin
       select @sql = 'IF OBJECT_ID('''+@stg_table+''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE '+@stg_table
    end
    else if @insert_type = 'insert'
    begin
       select @sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @stg_table
    end

    print @sql -- "debugging"

    -- only do those once if you can, so you don't get lost in how the code branches
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    fetch next from kursor into @insert_type, @stg_table, @src;
end
```

Also, you don't really need a cursor for that. You can just generate a big query and execute it once.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @sql += CONCAT(CASE
                        WHEN meta.insert_table = 'select'
                         AND OBJECT_ID(meta.stg_table) IS NOT NULL
                        THEN CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', meta.stg_table)

                        WHEN meta.insert_table = 'insert'
                        THEN CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE', meta.stg_table)
                      END,
                      ';', CHAR(13), CHAR(10)) -- add newline for easier reading
  FROM METADATA.dbo.META_SOURCESTAGE meta

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

This should work and although I haven't tested it, I hope you get the idea.